# Selenium Editing Attribute within Class

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have recently been doing work Selenium for GPS data processing.  Recently, the site I use to process data has changed quite dramatically and my old code no longer functions correctly.  Below is a snippet of the new HTML that I need to edit.  Is there any way to change the 'title' attribute from 'NONE' to something like 'TRM55971.00 NONE' (the actual antenna my GPS data was collected with) within the class?  Thanks for the help in advance!

If you are interested here is link: https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/OPUS/

```html
<span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-ant_type-container" title="NONE">NONE</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the `'title'` attribute from **'NONE'** to **'TRM55971.00 NONE'** you can use the following code block :

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('select2-ant_type-container').title='TRM55971.00 NONE';");
```